# AWS CodeCommit Git bash remote-codecommit SSL Issue running pipelines

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, git-bash, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

Strange issue with two machines both setup the same.

One can run code commit fine, the other can't - it gets the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/xxx/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

When running the command:

```
git clone codecommit://alias@pipeline-name
```

Now to add confusion, when the machine that has the SSL error has ZScaler disabled it works.

However the machine that works has ZScaler enabled.

Both machines have the same ZScaler profiles.

Both machines use the same VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added my Zscaler Cert to the Git CA store and I was able to bypass the error.

Run `git config http.sslCAInfo` to get the location of your CA store and then concatenate your Zscaler cert to this file.